# NavMesh Agent Does Not Touch Ground

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I created an algorithm that creates a different ground every time the game starts, so I bake with NavMesh Surface at runtime (only once when the game started). The problem is navmesh agent do not touch the ground as it must be. its y position is set to 0, but when the game starts its y position updates to "0.08240414".

Here is some screenshots to hopefully help you to understand the problem better.

[agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI6Vh.png)

[baked scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF14s.png)

Comment: check where your colliders end.. chances are they are below its "feet" should it have them

Comment: or the ground colliders are above the visual and the surface is higher than it should be.

Comment: @BugFinder I checked where agents' colliders end. Even though they were not below, I edited the colliders to stay strictly above, but that didn't work.

Comment: @hijinxbassist  Every ground piece had their own mesh collider with untick Convex. When I ticked it, the colliders look fine, not above the visual. Whatever I removed mesh colliders but didn't work.

Comment: So. There are likely the colliders to do with the rigid body. The controller and the colliders.

Comment: @BugFinder I'm not sure if I understand right, but if you're saying what I understand, There is not a rigidbody. I use character controller for agents.